# D3 Simple Line chart not drawing line in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am pretty fresh to both D3 and angular so I'm not exactly sure which portion is the problem. I'm writing an app that takes in data from an API and then renders a line graph of the data on the page. Currently the page draws axis and scales them appropriately to the data sent in through the api - but I've been unable to get any kind of line to show up. I'm a little fuzzy on the mechanics of the d3.line function in angular, but fiddling around with it has failed to change the line at all.

The code for my makeChart() function is below:

```
  makeChart(){
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = this.d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

    var x = this.d3.scaleTime()
    .range([0, width])

    var y = this.d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = this.d3.axisBottom(x)

    var yAxis = this.d3.axisLeft(y)

    var line = this.d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d['date']); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d['amount']); });
    console.log(line)


    var svg = this.d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var data = this.housingDataArray.map(function(d) {
      return {
         date: parseDate(d[0]),
         amount: d[1]
      }
  })


  x.domain(this.d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(this.d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.amount; }));

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

    svg.append("path")
      .data(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", <any>line);

}
```

I'm using this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/T546B/) for reference. The data we're working with is almost the exact same - his example array has some preset numbers, but the data I'm chewing through is also a set of 2 item arrays that contain a date at index 0 and a number at index 1.

I've tried plugging a lot of different stuff into the .x and .y functions on .line - but none of them seem to have any effect. The line that gets console logged is included below - I'm thinking no data is being set to the line. I believe I have some fundamental misunderstanding of the .line function, but the documentation is dense and I've made zero headway.

EDIT: Here is the code that invokes the function

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.grabRentPerSquareFoot()
  }
grabRentPerSquareFoot(){
    this.http.get('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/ZILL/Z60618_RZSF.json').subscribe(response => {
        this.housingDataArray = response.json().dataset.data
        console.log(this.housingDataArray)
        this.makeChart()
    })
  }
```

EDIT SOLVED: It turned out to be a syntax error, I was using "Data" instead of "datum" after calling the response.

Comment: your data array is not empty?

Comment: Nope! When I console log the data variable I'm creating inside that function I get an array of length 76. Each of the items in that array is a two value array that holds a date and a number

Comment: How is `makeChart()` called?

Comment: That's a good thought. Currently there's a function that's run in ngOnInit that makes a get request to the api. Within that function I'm calling the the 'makeChart()' function to ensure there's data. I've added the block that calls it in an edit above.

Comment: Try calling `makeChart()` inside `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: If I do that it draws both the axis of the chart but doesn't create any kind of scale for it, since the data has not been fed in yet.

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit()` is called **way after** `ngOnInit()` but glad you figured it out, should always check the console first when something is not working

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't actually throwing up a syntax error in the console because .data is valid - it just led to it trying to grab something that was non-existent down the road, which is why line was forever unchanging. Good to know about ngAfterViewInit, thanks for your help.